# How to make browser cache images in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class ItemGrid extends React.Component {

handleCart = (id) => {
    this.props.addFunction(id);
}

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    var itemArray = this.props.items;
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        if (itemArray[i].category == 6) {
            newArray.push(itemArray[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        if (itemArray[i].category != 6) {
            newArray.push(itemArray[i]);
        }
    }
    itemArray = newArray;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={8} className={classes.container}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid container className="item-grid" justify="space-evenly" alighitems="center" spacing={0}>
                    {itemArray.map(function(item, id) {
                    return  <Paper className={classes.gridItem} key={id}>
                        {getImage(classes, item)}
                        <Typography className={classes.itemName}>{item.name}</Typography>
                        <Typography className={classes.itemPrice}>Price: {numberWithCommas(item.price)} ISK</Typography>
                        <div className={classes.addButtonDiv}>
                        <Button variant="contained" className={classes.addButton} onClick={() => this.handleCart(item.id)}>
                            Add to cart
                            <CartIcon/>
                        </Button>
                        </div>
                        </Paper>
                    }, this)}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function getImage(classes, item) {
if (item.category == 6) {
    return <div className={classes.itemImg}><img src={"https://image.eveonline.com/Render/" + item.id + "_256.png"} alt={item[1]} className={classes.itemImg}></img></div>
} else {
    return <div className={classes.itemImg}><img src={"https://image.eveonline.com/Type/" + item.id + "_64.png"} alt={item[1]} className={classes.itemImg}></img></div>
}
}
```

So I have a search bar at the top of this grid of items that can be bought by the user. Everytime i search though I see the "getting data from image.eveonline.com" message so i'm assuming the browser is not properly caching the images for use later. When a component re-renders are cached images destroyed? Is there any way to preserve them?

Comment: Have you looked at the browser n/w tab to see what's actually happening? Also the caching depends on the [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) for the image.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/S8Fgfw5.png These are the headers, it seems it should cache for about a week?